# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource error for post command

Tags: javascript, client-server

I am trying to send a post request to a server but I seem to keep getting this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://nim-rd.nuance.mobi:9443/nina-webapi/TTS/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Here is my javascript function:

```
function play(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open("POST", http_url, true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    request.setRequestHeader("nmaid", nmaid);
    request.setRequestHeader("nmaidkey", nmaidKey);
    request.responseType = "arraybuffer";

    request.send(JSON.stringify({
        text: "Hi my name is Ted",
        tts_type: "text"
    }));

    request.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
        console.log("Entered");
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
            console.log("Entered2");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the response header:

```
OPTIONS /nina-webapi/TTS/ HTTP/1.1
Host: nim-rd.nuance.mobi:9443
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type, nmaid, nmaidkey
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

and here is the request header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Allow: POST, TRACE, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(9.3.11.v20160721)
```

I did some research online and it looks like a post is not considered as a preflight request, so how come I keep getting this error? I have also tried adding the following to my code but with no luck...

```
    request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS");
```

Comment: You can't POST to a server from your own page if the server doesn't want you to. The way it indicates that it's OK is by including that header. Since the server in question is *not* including that header, you'll have to take a different approach.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for the reply, so how else can i approach this?

Comment: Well if you have control over the target server, make sure it responds with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. If you don't, then the best course of action is a proxy on a server you *do* control.